# Using JBoss BRMS to Create My Own Decision Table Application

Tags: java, jboss, drools, rules

I am using the open-source **JBoss BRMS** application from jboss.org. Hopefully, if you clicked on this post you are familiar with this web application that can be used to develop applications that use Drools rules.

I am following along with the tutorial on building an application that uses a Decision Table to create the rules. That tutorial can be found here: http://www.jboss.org//quickstarts/brms/decision-table/index.html. I was able to successfully execute this tutorial after modifying the pom.xml some.

**My question is how can I create my own similar application?** This example application works by importing some Java classes into the BRMS repository and also putting a pre-configured Settings.xml file in the ./m2 Maven repository. There are also some folders at another location on my computer that contain 1) a pom.xml file and 2) a src and test directory which contain other things like java source files, compiled byte-code, and some XML files. How can I do this on my own and build my own JBoss BRMS Decision Table application? I was able to create some classes and a spreadsheet and validated this with JBoss BRMS but I am still confused on how to a) create the pom.xml file, b) create the Settings.xml file, and c) create the folders with the required program files like java source code to use Maven to build and run.

I have been reading the Drools documentation and the ["proprietary documentation"](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_BRMS/6.0/html/User_Guide/chap-Introduction.html#JBoss_BRMS) from Red Hat on the business rules management system (BRMS) that is not too helpful as of yet. It is somewhat helpful but not really. I call it "proprietary documentation" because it is on access.redhat.com which requires a subscription to even download trial software. Jboss.org has completely free versions of similar software. I hope this made sense. Please reply in the comments if it did not make any sense to you.

Respectfully,

user3870315

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I've just started looking into BRMS and I'm hoping that it will be possible to interact with it from an external app using some kind of API to 1) add/remove/modify rules and 2) execute the rules against a set of input data.

Comment: I am lucky to *not* have to use the software any more. I have no idea on how to do what you are asking. Good luck. :D You can do it.